# What is difference between onmyo talismans of different levels?

Tags: nioh

In Nioh, player can create talismans, using onmyo magic skills. There are skills to create various types of talismans, but most of them have 3 levels, and created talismans have corresponding level indications ("I", "II" and "III").

What is the difference between such talismans? Are they different by stats, or simply allow to have more talismans of kind by assigning them to different slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the talismans themselves, but there is a difference in Jutsu-costs, e.g. a XYZ I may cost 4 jutsu points for 3 talismans, whereas XYZ II only costs 3.

Thus, you can use these levels to

- accumulate more talismans of the same type, and/or
- reduce jutsu-cost by using higher levels